# Is there a proof that OEIS-A002387 is $[ e^{n-\gamma} ]$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, oeis

Based on the comments on [OEIS-A002387](https://oeis.org/A002387):

$a_{n}$ = 1, 2, 4, 11, 31, 83, 227, 616,...

it is likely, that the sequence $a_{n}$ coincides with $[ e^{n-\gamma} ]$ ,
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $[\cdot]$ is the rounding function (remark made by Dean Hickerson).

My Question: Is there a formal proof, that OEIS-A002387 is $[ e^{n-\gamma} ]$ ?

Comment: Equivalently, there exist no integers $k \ge 1$ and $n$ with $\log(k+1/2) + \gamma < n < \log(k+1/2) + \gamma + 1/(24k^2)$.

Comment: As $a_{n}$ essentially grows as a geometric progression of common ratio $e$, maybe there is a way to derive the analogue of Binet's formula for the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @Gerald I suppose there might exists integers in your equality, yet the value of $H_k$ to be the floor of the lower bound and the conjecture will be still true.

Comment: I doubt a proof is known or can be obtained using any known techniques.  Basically, it comes down to whether a bizarre numerical coincidence occurs with Euler's contant $\gamma$.  The approximation properties of $\gamma$ seem intractable, which makes the problem feel hopeless, but I guess you never know where a nice argument might be hiding (or I might be overlooking some aspect of this).

Comment: Let me summarize. $k=a(n)$ means $$n\in I_k:=[H(k-1),H(k) )$$
$k=\lfloor e^{n-\gamma} +0.5\rfloor$ is equivalent to 
$$n\in J_k:=[L(k-1), L(k) ),$$ 
for $L(k):=\log(k+1/2)+\gamma$. Asymptotics for $H$ and $L$ imply that $I_k$ and $J_k$ are quite close intervals, which makes more and more likely that $I_k$ meets $\mathbb{N}$ iff $J_k$ does (the thesis being that this is true for all $k$). 
Moreover, it is encouraging that $H(k)$ is never an integer for $k > 1$ (a consequence of the Bertrand's postulate), that is, if an integer $n$ is in $I_k$, it is not on its boundary. 

Comment: So a possible strategy could be, improve this fact in a quantitative way, showing that if $n$ is in $I_k$, then it is close enough to its center, so that in fact $n\in I_k\cap J_k$. 

Comment: As a matter of fact, $H(k)-L(k)=1/24k^2+o(1/k^2)$. So for instance if we knew that
$$\liminf_{k\to\infty}k^2 \operatorname{frac}H(k) > 1/24$$
we could decuce that the equality $a(n)=\lfloor e^{n-\gamma} +0.5\rfloor$ holds for $n$ large.

Comment: Dear All, thank you very much for your quick and dedicated feedback!

Comment: @Pietro: Thanks, I have to think about that approach!

Comment: @joro: Thanks for editing the original post. I now changed $\lfloor e^{n-\gamma} + 0.5 \rfloor $ to $[e^{n-\gamma}]$, as it looks more compact.

Comment: @Henry: To me, the connection between $\gamma$ and OEIS-A002387 (based on the harmonic series) does not look like a coincidence. However, I also assume, that prooving that OEIS-A002387 is $[e^{n−γ}]$ might be difficult or impossible.

Comment: Also notice that if the above limit inferior were *smaller* than $1/24$, there would be infinitely many exceptions to $A002387(n)=[e^{n-\gamma}]$.

Comment: @Pietro: I agree with your approach, but I do not see how to proof the above limit inferior (for $k>1$).

Comment: @jojo: You are right, my inequalities are not equivalent.  But the heuristic in favor of the conjecture is this statement.  Now, in fact, this holds for *almost all* real numbers $\gamma$, not only for Euler's constant.  So the question becomes: why is Euler's constant not in a certain set of measure zero?  Since we cannot prove even that Euler's constant is irrational, it seems unlikely we can prove this!

Comment: @Martin: of course, proving that the limit inferior is larger than 1/24 is difficult task. But notice that it is almost equivalent to the statement. Besides, it is possible that these arithmetic properties of the partial sums of the harmonic series have already been studied.

 